# Scrapy Extract Values of tags

Tags: json, web-scraping, scrapy

I am handling a json request that has a div as a value.
Now I want to get only the values of data-content-value

```
<li id="term_100800962"  data-content-value='{"nl_term_id":100800962,"c_price_from":33415,"nd_price_discount":0,"nl_tour_id":1017864,"nl_hotel_id":[49316],"d_start":"2017-04-12","d_end":"2017-04-17"}' >
```

and store them in 'dates' 'id' 'price' and I can't figure out a way to do this.

Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [2]: from scrapy.selector import Selector

In [3]: text = """<li id="term_100800962"  data-content-value='{"nl_term_id":100
   ...: 800962,"c_price_from":33415,"nd_price_discount":0,"nl_tour_id":1017864,"
   ...: nl_hotel_id":[49316],"d_start":"2017-04-12","d_end":"2017-04-17"}' >"""

In [4]: sel = Selector(text=text)

In [5]: data_string = sel.xpath('//li/@data-content-value').extract_first()

In [6]: import json

In [7]: json.loads(data_string)
Out[7]: 
{'c_price_from': 33415,
 'd_end': '2017-04-17',
 'd_start': '2017-04-12',
 'nd_price_discount': 0,
 'nl_hotel_id': [49316],
 'nl_term_id': 100800962,
 'nl_tour_id': 1017864}
```

First, get the string of the attribute, then use `json.loads()` convert it to python dict.

This url will return a json response, we should loads all response to json and select the info we need:

```
In [11]: fetch('https://dovolena.invia.cz/direct/tour_search/ajax-next-boxes/?nl
...: _country_id%5B0%5D=28&nl_locality_id%5B0%5D=19&d_start_from=23.01.2017&
...: d_end_to=19.04.2017&nl_transportation_id%5B0%5D=3&sort=nl_sell&page=1&g
...: etOptionsCount=true&base_url=https%3A%2F%2Fdovolena.invia.cz%2F')

In [12]: j = json.loads(response.text)
In [15]: j['boxes_html']  # this will renturn the html in json file.
In [15]: from scrapy.selector import Selector

In [16]: sel = Selector(text=j['boxes_html'])  # loads html to selector

In [17]: datas = sel.xpath('//li/@data-content-value').extract() # return all data in a list
In [21]: [json.loads(d) for d in datas]  # loads text to value
          |---dict-----|
# this will return a list of dict which generated by json.loads(d), and you can use json.loads(d)['d_end'] to access it's element.
```

out:

```
[{'c_price_from': 15690,
  'd_end': '2017-04-16',
  'd_start': '2017-04-09',
  'nd_price_discount': 27,
  'nl_hotel_id': [24810],
  'nl_term_id': 93902083,
  'nl_tour_id': 839597},
 {'c_price_from': 27371,
  'd_end': '2017-04-17',
  'd_start': '2017-04-12',
  'nd_price_discount': 4,
  'nl_hotel_id': [49316],
  'nl_term_id': 100804770,
  'nl_tour_id': 1017864},
 {'c_price_from': 32175,
  'd_end': '2017-04-17',
  'd_start': '2017-04-12',
  'nd_price_discount': 4,
  'nl_hotel_id': [49316],
  'nl_term_id': 100800962,
  'nl_tour_id': 1017864},
```

Comment: I would be very glad if you could help me this is the coding im running in scrapy shell [link](http://pastebin.com/MYuER5xf)

Comment: Ok check the last error I think I am facing. I wrote above that I want to store the seperately but it doesnt allow me. I think this is the final step sorry for my misunderstooding. [link](http://imgur.com/a/brMVq)

Comment: @Kostas The idea is clear and I will not spend time on this question.

Comment: I am a beginer it's clear and obvious for you why I am getting this error but for me it's not. Sorry for your time .

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate your patience.